# Why the unused argument appears in converting likert scale to fuzzy set with R?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the variables that are set in the Likert scale into the Fuzzy set; however, an error appears (unused argument). My code and the error is below: Really appreciate your help

bas <- function(x,a,b,m,n) m+(n-m)*((x-a)/b-a))

```
bin <- function(x) x-1
Dataset$GEN_F <- bin(GEN)

bas <- function(x,a,b,m,n) m+(n-m)*((x-a)/(b-a))
likert <- function(x,q,w,e,r,t,y,u)
   ifelse(x < 2, bas(x,1,2,q,w),
            ifelse(x >= 2 & x < 3, bas(x,2,3,w,e),
                    ifelse(x >= 3 & x < 4, bas(x,3,4,e,r),
                             ifelse(x >= 4 & x <= 5, bas(x,4,5,r,t),
                                     ifelse(x >= 5 & x <= 6, bas(x,5,6,t,y),
                                                   ifelse(x >= 6, x <= 7, bas(x,6,7,y,u),0))))))


c <- 0
v <- 0.15
b <- 0.3
k <- 0.45
l <- 0.45 + 0.55/3
o <- 0.45 + 2 * 0.55/3
p <- 1
```

Dataset$PC2C_F <- likert(PC2C,c,v,b,k,l,o,p)

Error in ifelse(x >= 6, x <= 7, bas(x, 6, 7, y, u), 0) :
unused argument (0)

```
To can solve the problem and error.
```

Comment: The error message is quite informative.  You have too many arguments, because there is a `,` where,presumably another operator is intended, such as `|`

Comment: The error message shows you where the problem is: `ifelse(x >= 6, x <= 7, bas(x, 6, 7, y, u), 0)`. `ifelse` is a function that takes three parameters, but you seem to be passing in 4 (you have three commas). Using `x >= 6 & x <= 7` instead would match your other cases.